# Unspecified System Error using nodejs driver to connect to informix

Tags: node.js, informix

I have this connection below. Works well in windows server but when in linux it doesnt. It provides this erro msg :`an error occured:> Error: [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unspecified System Error =  -23101.`
when I check on the error code using finderr it says the locale environment variables `DB_LOCALE` and `CLIENT_LOCALE` has problem how do I go about this? How can I set the locales or find the problem and solve it. Note that I have installed the CSDK and set the environment varibales as required my connection is as below code.

```
var ibmdb = require("ifxnjs");
    var ConnectionString = "SERVER=ict_tcp;DATABASE=biolive;HOST=128.1.9.144;SERVICE=1541;UID=biouser;PWD=bihif20;";

    ibmdb.open(ConnectionString, function (err, connection) {
        if (err) 
        {
          console.log("an error occured:> "+err);
          return;
        }
        connection.query("select 1 from mytab1", function (err1, rows) 
        {
          if (err1) console.log(err1);
          else console.log(rows);
          connection.close(function(err2) 
          { 
            if(err2) console.log(err2);
          });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Error 23101 is "Unable to load locale categories". Basically, the driver can't load the locale files required based on your CLIENT_LOCALE/DB_LOCALE. But in your case, you are  also failing to get the proper error message ('unable to load ...') , instead you have an ('unspecific error') which usually means that, it's not just the GLS files that are failing to load, but everything else, e.g error message files.

One of the reasons you may get that, is if your INFORMIXDIR is not set (it has to be set to the directory where you installed CSDK) or your user has no permissions to read the files.

Comment: I extracted the files to location /opt/informix so I made `INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix` is this some how done wrong? then right now have given permissions to root `rwx` to all files and folders in `INFORMIXDIR` but its persistence

Comment: umm, extracted from?.. best option is always do a proper install, but before that, why not getting a strace/truss trace of the execution. It should show what is failing to load.

Comment: extracted the files from a tar file, that contained the CSDK files to the location opt/informix that exposed the /lib,/bin, folders that it contained. sure I ll check on the strace/truss trace execution..I really appreciate this

Comment: should the csdk files come with a folder called GLS? because its missing in mine. as per your first comment. am getting the same message if I run any other informix command.

Comment: yes, and a msg directory too. Where did you get the tar file from? The normal CSDK install is to first untar the media package (which will left you with a big installclienksdk file, then you run that and it will uncompress all the files, change the permissions and 'enable' the binaries for execution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176636/discussion-between-j-s-and-carlos-murray).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my CSDK files were not complete I did not have the gls(global locale support) folder, which provides language support for informix .Incase you know you have set the environment variables properly but still get errors, try checking your CSDK files if all are installed properly or some are missing.